# Selenide profiler in TestNG

Tags: testng, selenide

I have problem to generate profiler report(with TestNG) in my TC.

As it is written on `selenide.org page`, I add following :

```
@Listeners(TextReport.class)
@Report
public class GoogleTest {
   ...
}
```

Test is correctly running, but I do not see the profiler report.

Do you have any idea, how can I fix it and see the report?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `slf4j` in your classpath.

Add `testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.30'` to your gradle.build .

Or in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```